# Angular Project Structure For Enterprise Projects

Tags: angular

I'm about to start a fairly large project that will use Angular for it's front end and I had a question about how to manage it's growth to maximize maintainability.

For every angular project up until this point, I've had a views folder that mimics the routing hierarchy and my module structure has been based off of grouping of business feature.  This has worked well with onboarding new devs and for maintenance purposes for these small to mid-size apps.

My question centers more around when to use modules in a large enterprise app.

I've recently heard about creating a module per page and/or module per component.  This approach seems like a ton of up front overhead but a lot of savings in test creation and long term maintenance.

I don't see any guidance in the angular.io style guide regarding one way or another but I'd like to know from people that have built enterprise sized angular applications if they've found a particular way that works well for them.

**UPDATE**
I got a lot of great answers here.  I believe that all emphasized the common points of module by feature and extra modules for the core, shared (and resources that bryan mentioned).  I am also going to move my routing views into their respective feature folder as opposed to the "views" folder that I currently use.  After reading the answers below, the "views" folder might get tricky to manage down the road as the application grows.

Someone had also suggested I read up on what Nrwl is doing and so I did that and was intrigued by their usage of libraries as separate from the app.  [Nrwl MonoRepo Pattern Book (Free)](https://connect.nrwl.io/app/books/enterprise-angular-monorepo-patterns) .  They had a lot of good advice that ran parallel to what everybody said here with the addition of abstracting away common functionality across platforms into libraries.  Since I am sure the app I am building will require targeting mobile devices outside of the web world, this seemed like a good idea as well.

Thank you to everybody that took the time to respond in great detail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A lot of good answers here, I have a slight differentiation that I've found helpful in building larger apps that I don't see mentioned so far, and that is a differentiation between a feature and a resource.  A feature is something your app does, and a resource is something your app uses. A feature could be using one or more resources, and I think this is important to be reflected in your project structure.

typically I'll have something like:

```
app/
  core/
    ... core stuff like nav bars and single use components or core services...
  app-shared/ (prefix it!!!!)
    ... shared app utilities like tables, accordions, validators, form helpers, pipes etc ...
  resource1/ <- represents some backend resource usually
    resource1.model <- the models
    resource1-model.service <- API interaction layer, single http calls
    resource1-domain.service <- abstraction for everything I can do with this resource (think combinations of multiple model service calls or model service calls with common defaults)
    views/
      ... here we have all the components (data views, forms etc) that concern only this resource and the needed view services ...
  ... rinse repeat for all app resources ...
  feature1/ <- this is an application feature that combines multiple resources or possibly only uses a single resource. this is pretty much primarily a page of your app
    feature1-application.service <- this combines the various resources needed for this feature
    feature1-container.component <- the prime container for this feature. does the service layer interactions and holds the views of this feature or the needed resource views
    views/ <- maybe not needed depending on the feature
      ... here is where we have components and view services that are part of this feature that combine multiple resources, these can contain resource views if needed ...
  ... rinse repeat for all app features ...
```

notes:

1. a model service is API interaction exclusively for a single resource, they call one and only one action on the API
2. domain services take model services and make them useful and easy for a developer. Can have a tightly related sub resource model service injected.
3. application services combine multiple domain services
4. view services take data from a domain or application service and build a view model for a specific view (PLEASE don't ever pass a backend model straight through to a template!! you will hate yourself if / when that backend model gets refactored... related to this, keeps templates as simple as humanly possible. Don't have a complex template expression determining if a button should show, build a view model with a "showButton" property and assign it there!)
5. resources typically won't have routing, unless it's to like a routed modal if you're into that kind of thing. features are really your app structure with routing, the prime segment will point to the prime container and then the views will be children (if needed), but they make use of the resource views.
6. if you're doing this right, theoretically you should be able to lift your resources straight out and into another app that uses the same resource (with some styling of course).
7. the reason you may not need any sub views in a feature is because the container could be enough. Suppose you have a teacher resource with a data list component and a school resource with a data view component and you want a feature that shows these side by side, the container here just needs to position these two resource views and facilitate any interaction between them via the feature application service. containers don't display data or have UX, they just hold views that do these things.
8. you frequently also end up with single resource features in order to have your features match your true app structure better, and also to provide flexibility to add more resources in the future to the feature.
9. A tightly related resource view may end up in a different resource view in the case of a shared sub resource. Think like if there’s a tags resource that has a special multi select auto complete form. This is a tightly coupled shared sub resource that could appear on multiple other resources, so for ease, it could of course end up inside a resource view though they are typically single resource per resource view.
10. MOST IMPORTANT: when you start building, a lot of this will look like you're just building weird one to one pass throughs to other services (IE your domain might look like it just wraps your model and your application might look like it wraps your domains) but as the app grows, you'll be thankful you made the up front one time investment into building these layers. What I've learned about enterprise front end dev, is that requirements change pretty much daily and the business is never quite sure of what they want until they see it in action.  These abstraction layers provide the flexibility needed to react quickly to changing circumstances while still having an easy to reason about code base.

Comment: This is interesting. I like the idea of features vs resources. In my projects I more or less use `/shared/` to denote that something is a "resource" to be used by multiple features. If I want something to be shared across multiple projects, I try to extract it as a library.

Comment: I tend to think of shared as stuff local to the application itself. I hesitate to use the term resources there because I strictly use it to define the actual models and whatnot exposed by my api or used by my application. They’re sort of external in a sense. But the stuff under shared I think or more as stuff you might Put in a library like tables and whatnot (tended towards libraries for this lately), or possibly app specific pipes and validators. I find putting any “shared” resources (like maybe a tags or codes type object) in shared makes it too bloated.

Comment: what is the difference between  /core and /shared folders?

Answer (score 7):

First off: I have built a few Enterprise apps using Angular over the years and have seen things that work and things that I wish I had never tried. The good news is: refactoring/dev tools are so good these days you can switch your project structure mid-project when you find it has become unruly. The only bad news is: it will create merge nightmares that will test your git-fu.

The style guide does mention [folders by feature](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#folders-by-feature-structure) which sounds like what you are already doing. I would stick with what you are currently doing and it should scale. You already have experience with it, it's working, and trying something totally different for your first time running a larger app sounds like a recipe for disaster.

The main thing to avoid is to have an unnecessarily complex folder structure that doesn't actually mirror the structure of your app. For example, if you have a profile management section, don't put it in `/dashboard/user/components/profile/edit` or something arbitrary like that unless it actually mimics your app structure. It seems obvious, but people do this all the time and it makes your code less easy to discover. I think this is covered by the [LIFT](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#lift) concept:

> **Do** structure the app such that you can Locate code quickly, Identify the code at a glance, keep the Flattest structure you can, and Try to be DRY.
>
> **Do** define the structure to follow these four basic guidelines, listed in order of importance.
>
> **Why?** LIFT Provides a consistent structure that scales well, is modular, and makes it easier to increase developer efficiency by finding code quickly. To confirm your intuition about a particular structure, ask: can I quickly open and start work in all of the related files for this feature?

It goes on to mention keeping a flat folder structure as much as possible:

> **Do** keep a flat folder structure as long as possible.
>
> **Consider** creating sub-folders when a folder reaches seven or more files.
>
> **Consider** configuring the IDE to hide distracting, irrelevant files such as generated .js and .js.map files.
>
> **Why?** No one wants to search for a file through seven levels of folders. A flat structure is easy to scan.

This is one of the most crucial points in terms of large projects. When you are working on an app with 20 modules, an unnecessarily complex folder structure is a mild annoyance. When you get to 150 modules, you will instinctively cringe when you open your IDE. The [overall structural guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#overall-structural-guidelines) is a good starting point for a project and demonstrates when to keep `/feature/` vs when to use sub-feature folders.

Regarding a module per component:

> **Do** create an NgModule for each feature area.
>
> **Why?** NgModules make it easy to lazy load routable features.
>
> **Why?** NgModules make it easier to isolate, test, and reuse features.

You could extend that to say that you should create a module for each component, but I would actually avoid it unless you have a specific need for a given module. Again - in my experience, creating overhead for yourself gets even **more** cumbersome the larger your project gets. Those things that seem slightly annoying in small projects become nightmares in large projects.

Final note: be open to change. You and your colleagues can spend a week planning your project structure only to find, once you start actually using it, that it feels wrong. It's hard to get things 100% correct on your first try. It's easier to slowly iterate until you reach something that is near perfect.

My projects usually look something like this:

```
app/
| core/ 
| | constants/         // Keep all constants in a single place and avoid magic IDs/strings.
| | |-http-status-codes.enum.ts
| | guards/            // I like to group my guards in a single place
| | http-interceptors/ // Same with interceptors
| | pipes/             // Some pipes might be section-specific but they are usually core
| | services/          // Core services. Utilities, error handling, etc.
| | |-error-handler.service.ts
| | validators/
| section1/
| | models/
| | sub1/              // I try not to nest too deeply
| | |-sub1.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
| |-section1-routing.module.ts // Routing by section
| |-section1.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
| |-section1.module.ts  // Module per section for lazy loading, etc.
| |-section1.service.ts // Section-specific service
| shared/
| | models/
| | app-modal-dialog/
| | my-awesome-widget/
| | some-custom-input/
|-app.component.ts|html|css|spec.ts
|-app.module.ts
|-app-routing.module.ts
assets/             // Static content
environments/
|-environment.x.ts  // Stripe public keys, etc.
```

Again - this is pretty consistent with the [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#file-tree).

Comment: Do you keep a "views" like folder at the app root level that mimics the routing tree or do you include a view folder in each of your feature folders to handle routing for just that feature module?  Right now, we have the views folder at the app root and that helps a lot with locating the primary view of a root quickly but it separates the view from the folder feature module that that view belongs to.

Comment: I am in favor of having routing modules as a peer of each feature module and living in the same folder. So, if you have a `/feature/` folder, you would have `feature/feature.module.ts` and `feature/feature-routing.module.ts`. It's consistent with the style guide.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of what my apps might look like.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I try to use LIFT Guidelines when structuring an app:

- Location our code is easy
- Identify code at a glance
- Flat structure as long as we can
- Try to stay DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

Then my folder structure is like:

```
app/
  core/
    models/             // All models
    not-found/          // A core feature (not-found component for example)
    ...
    core.module.ts
  feature1/             // Feature 1 folder
    sub-feature1-1/     // A sub feature for the feature 1
    sub-feature1-2/     // A sub feature for the feature 1
    feature1.service.ts
    feature1.module.ts
  feature2/             // Feature 2 folder
    sub-feature2-1/     // A sub feature for the feature 2
    sub-feature2-2/     // A sub feature for the feature 2
    feature1.service.ts
    feature1.module.ts
  shared/
    card/               // A shared feature (card component for example)
    ...
    shared.module.ts
  app-routing.module.ts
  app.component.html
  app.component.scss
  app.component.spec.ts
  app.component.ts
  app.module.ts
```

In this structure, I always try to keep only one level on sub feature. All feature should be as independent as possible and should have only one responsibility.

Comment: Do you use a views folder at the app root level to mimic routing paths to keep your views organized? Or do you organize your views in a different way?

Answer (score 3):

I will go a module per domain for example authentication module where I have the register, login and forgot password, product module, payments module and so on. A module per view is a total overhead. Angular documentation strongly support core module for common services and shared module for the common components and directives cross the App. Every module should have components, directives and services directory as needed. Also you could use barrel for directory has many elements for clean import in the module. It's highly recommended not to nest the components directory.

It's a good idea to make a separated routing module for modules has many view.

```
// barrel 
import { firstComponent, .... ,lastComponent } from './components'; 

const routs = [ ... ];

export class FeatureRoutingModule { 
    const static components = [
       firstComponent,
             .
             .
             .
       lastComponent
    ]
};
```

Then in the feature module you could import it that way. That will help you not to import your components multiple times if you separated routing.

```
import { FeatureRoutingModule } from './freature-rotuing.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule, // if you have one
    FeatureRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [FeatureRoutingModule.components]
  })
  export class FeatureModule { }
```

I hope that help you to better organize your code, Good luck.